# Displaying a String of text (N) number of times

Tags: java, loops, display

For an assignment i have to create a program that creates a prompt for the user to enter a number (N), and then creates another prompt that then asks the user for a line of text. Which then the program has to display the line of text (N) number of times

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a postivie integer: " );
        int n = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine(); //consume the rest of the line

        System.out.println("Enter a line of text: ");
        String text = kb.nextLine();
```

From this point onwards is where im having the trouble of implementing a loop which will display the text (N) number of times

```
for(int n; n<0; n--){
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int i = n; i >=0; i--

Comment: I made that modification, but now the program is displaying the text over and over again forever

Comment: You redeclare n in your for loop scope, so your actually overloading int n = kb.nextInt(); Since you don't explicitly specify an initialization value, 0 will be used, resulting in not a single for loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the head of the for loop you declare a new variable n that gets a vaue of 0 assigned.

You could use this (not recommended):

```
for(; n>0; n--)
```

Or better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: It's advisable not to use the first version of the for loop. It changes the value of the user's input `n` to 1 after the for loop. Always use the second approach.

Comment: @cdaiga: Right, I just included it because it is closer to the original code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your loop won't start. What you're asking your loop to do is
Start at n. Keep the loop going as long as n is less than 0 (which it isn't. n is supposed to be greater than 0). Decrease n by 1.
I think what you were trying to do is

```
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you declared a new variable. This variable n makes the other n used to get the value n invisible in the for loop as it's overridden. Another error you made in your for loop is that you did not initialize the variable you are using to iterate. So you where supposed to use the for loop on this case like below:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
     ...
  }
```

The variable j is use to make the number of iterations. In this case j iterates from 0 to n - 1 with a step of 1. That is iterating n times. You have to be careful to test the value of n from the user to verify it's a positive number else the for loop won't work well.